# sonarqube enterprise level installation

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to know if there is any industry best standard architecture to roll-out sonarqube at an enterprise level.

Just to be provide more context to the question -
   For an enterprise with multiple organizations which would in-turn have multiple business units.
   Across the all the B.U's and organizations around 2500-4000 developers with 750-1500 applications for scanning.

1. A) Is it better to setup an individual sonarqube for each organization ?

   - This would not clutter the instance and also would give a clear idea of all porfolio's in that organization.

   or
    
   B) Would it be better to have a singe central sonarqube for all the organizations ?
2. What would be the typical logical architecture of the installation of such a large scale installations?

For each organization :
   A load-balancer in the front with 2 sonarqube instances with a failover mechanism .

or just have the DB cluster.
I have read in some forums that front-end cluster is not supported.  Let me know if there is any better architectural implementation of SonarSource Ultimate/Enterprise edition.

Comment: 1500 applications in one SonarQube instance is a bit too much. You will lose the overview.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm part of SonarSource - but be sure that my answer is honest though) If you really are in such a context (looks like a big company), then you should really consider contacting SonarSource to get help and support instead of trying to do things on your own. What's more, without the Governance product, it will be hard for you to answer all the stackholders' needs.